# What's the correct punctuation for the following phrase?

Tags: punctuation

Suppose I am discussing two books, one authored by John Smith and James Wilson, the other authored by Anthony Jones. In comparing the two books, I wish to say:

> 'The disagreement between Jones and Smith and Wilson is not something that will addressed in this article'.

The problem with the above is that it is unclear that Smith and Wilson should be grouped together as co-authors. Alternately, I could say:

> 'The disagreement between Jones, and Smith and Wilson, is not something that will be addressed in this article'.

The problem with the above is that the punctuation seems a little awkward. Is there a better way to express what I'm trying to say, or should I stick with the second version?

Comment: You could disambiguate by saying "Jones and Smith on one hand, and Wilson on the other..."

Comment: ...the disagreement Smith and Wilson have with Jones...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because writing advice like this belongs on [writers.se].

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation can only do so much for you.  And even though it could fix this consider writing in a style that will also make sense when read aloud.  You could fix this with:

> 'The disagreement between Jones - Smith and Wilson is not something that will addressed in this article'.

But I strongly urge you to avoid constructions like this.

Consider:

> 'The disagreement between Jones and Wilson is not something that will addressed in this article'.

Sure it's not fair to Smith but he didn't get top billing.  If he's been credited earlier you're off the hook.

Alternatively, you could just use the names of the books.

If the names of the books are even more unwieldy you can actually give them nicknames.  One of the most famous books on object oriented programming patterns is typically called "the gang of four book" because no one wants to recount either the name of the book or list all four of the authors.